# Styles not applying on web from tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, error-handling, tailwind-css, html-helper

I followed the tutorial perfectly and made a website while using the live server extension and it was applying. I use Chrome, Edge and Opera to check the `.html` file itself but no style was applied in the matter of fact it still shows as applied in the live server extension

[The files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LddYm.png)

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body class="m-0 bg-blue-500 p-0">
    <nav class="m-0 h-full w-full space-x-4 border bg-blue-400 p-6">
      <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold drop-shadow-md md:filter-none">
        Safer Internet
      </h1>
      <div
        class="absolute top-7 right-14 space-x-10 stroke-2 font-extrabold hover:stroke-black"
      >
        <button
          class="position inline-block text-right duration-700 hover:text-white"
        >
          <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
        </button>
        <button
          class="position inline-block text-right duration-700 hover:text-white"
        >
          <a href="./More.html">More</a>
        </button>
        <button
          class="position inline-block text-right duration-700 hover:text-white"
        >
          <a href="./About.html">About</a>
        </button>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div>
      <p
        class="absolute left-64 top-2/4 translate-x-2/4 translate-y-2/4 text-center text-xl font-bold"
      >
        To be able to know how to be safe on the internet click the button
        bellow.
      </p>
      <div
        class="relative top-96 flex translate-y-2/3 items-center justify-center text-center"
      >
        <button
          class="relative top-9 w-1/6 rounded-xl bg-blue-900 p-4 font-extrabold duration-700 hover:bg-black hover:text-white"
        >
          <a href="./More.html">More</a>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

tailwind.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}", "./public/*.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

style.css:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I tried everything and it didn't work and I expected the styles to apply on my browser.

Comment: NVM i found my issue i forgot to do the <link> to styles.css

Comment: It happened to me; I spent almost 30 minutes trying to figure out why Tailwind classes were not working in my Chrome browser, only to realize that I had forgotten to link my CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Proper approach to follow when using `Tailwind-CLI`

##### 1. Know about your file structure. Use:

```
public
|_ tailwind_base.css 
    File from which the output.css is produced
     @tailwind base;
     @tailwind components;
     @tailwind utilities;
|_ output.css
src
|_ index.html   
   Link with the output.css using 
    <link href="../public/output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

##### Watch it as

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./public/tailwind_base.css -o ./public/output.css --watch
```

##### Specify your `html/js` in `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Use `tailwindcss classes` happily in your `index.html` file

Comment: What about using them in other files like more or about.html

Comment: Any `html/js` files inside `src` can have tailwind-css classes, because of the RegExp `./src/**/*.{html,js}`